Signal disappearance in twin paradox
Given that time passes slower for the object moving, then if the stationary object emits photons at the fastest possible rate (plank time?) then not all the photons will be able to be received by the moving object (simply because it will not have enough plank times for all of them). Then the question is: What happens to the photons that cannot be received? Do they disappear from existence?

I think you would not get downvotes if you removed the part about "Planck times." That part is speculative, and not necessary for your underlying question. There is a reasonable question about special relativity if you remove that aspect.

I think this is relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_a_tree_falls_in_a_forest_and_no_one_is_around_to_hear_it%2C_does_it_make_a_sound%3F

Is not relevant at all.

I'm going to ignore the part about "fastest possible rate" and the Planck time, because that is quite speculative and underneath that is a reasonable question about special relativity.
The rate of photon arrival according to the observer gets redshifted (in other words, the rate decreases) relative to the rate of photon emission according to the source due to relativistic time dilation. So all photons that the source sends out, will arrive at the observer. You do correctly identify time dilation in that the observer's clock will run slowly in the source's frame, but your error is in not accounting for time dilation when you assume that the rate of photon emission in the source's frame must equal the rate of photon arrival in the observer's frame.
So, there is no contradiction, and all emitted photons are absorbed.
If you are familiar with spacetime diagrams, it helps to try to draw one out in this scenario. You will see that no matter how widely or narrowly spaced you make the 45 degree lines associated with the photons emitted by the source (the spacing of these lines corresponds to the rate of photon emission), all of them will cross the observer's worldline -- so the observer will receive all of the photons.

No they are not all absorbed. Imagine the stationary object sending a movie lasting 1000 years. For the moving object, those 1000 years will last 1 day. How come in 1 day watch a movie that lasts 1000 years ?

Those diagrams that you mention assume that photons can be emitted and absorbed arbitrarily fast. Is this really the case? Can atoms emit and absorb photons at any rate?

@Abc2000ro Andrew’s answer is correct. Your objection is not well founded. There is no evidence that the Planck time limits absorption

"How come in 1 day watch a movie that lasts 1000 years ?" that is a very good question, the way you phrased your posted question made it not understandable

So what is the answer ?

During the first half of the trip, he will see a very slow movie (only a few seconds of the movie are received), then on the second part of the trip the movie speeds up to fit almost 1000 years in half a day

How do you watch 1000 years in half a day ?

like watching a youtube video at x600,000 speed

That's the whole point: you cannot do that since you don't have enough plank times for all of them.

I don't know what you mean by that

Movies are made out of frames. There are not enough frames at destination as they are at the start.

You can have two frames as close as you want, even simultaneously, unless time is discrete (but that would require an update of the theory). You are confused about the meaning of the plank time.

What is the plank time ? You can emit and receive multiple photons in a single plank time ?

There is a familiar example you encounter every day. The Sun emits around 100 photons every Planck time. You do not absorb all of them. They do not disappear from existence as a consequence of not being 'received'.

I'm talking about the photons emitted in your direction. When there is a 1-to-1 correspondence between the rate of emission and the rate of absorption, then every photon is received. But if the source emits more photons than you have plank times for them, what happens to the extra ones ?

Nothing happens to them!!!! Why should anything 'happen' to them? If you are not able to absorb them, they will go past you and off into the Universe until they hit something else.

So photons pass through walls ?
